# Can't add pair<vector2d,double>(el1, el2) into static map<vector2d, double>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I've got class `Functions`. 
It contains of: `static std::map<vector2d, double> functionValues;`
Also I created my own `vector2d` clsss.
So, when I try to `insert`/`emplace` or add element through using of `operator[]` from member function of `Function` class into this `map` it fails. 
So, the error code is C2676. I found no answear, so really appreciate any suggestions what can cause this problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARrqa.png)
Here is some code:

```
#pragma once

#include "vector2d.h"
#include <map>
extern unsigned int functionCallCounts;

class Function
{
private:
    static std::map<vector2d, double> functionValues;
    static int coef;
public:
    inline static void setCoef(int _coef) { coef = _coef; };
    static double calcFunction(vector2d _point);
};
```

```
#include "Function.h"
#include <cmath>

std::map<vector2d, double> Function::functionValues;
int Function::coef;

unsigned int functionCallCounts;

double Function::calcFunction(vector2d _point)
{
    for (auto e : functionValues)
    {
        if (_point == e.first)
        {
            return e.second;
        }
    }
    double functionValue = 2 * pow((_point.x - coef), 2) - _point.x * _point.y + 5 * pow(_point.y, 2);
    ++functionCallCounts;
    functionValues.insert(std::make_pair(_point, functionValue));
    return functionValue;
}
```

And vector2d

```
class vector2d
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    vector2d operator* (double coef);
    vector2d operator+ (vector2d v2);
    vector2d operator- (vector2d v2);
    vector2d operator* (vector2d v2);
    vector2d operator/ (vector2d v2);
    vector2d operator/ (double devideBy);
    double magnitude() const;

    double distance(const vector2d& vec2d) const;
    vector2d normalizedVec();
    void makeNormalized();

    vector2d();
    vector2d(double _x, double _y);

    bool operator== (const vector2d v2) const;
    friend vector2d operator*(const double coef, vector2d& v);
};
```

Comment: Have you defined a suitable ordering operator?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with code in the question, as text.

Comment: @molbdnilo, no, thx, now i see